# insert data to 3 tables on one joomla view

Tags: mysql, joomla

What is the best way to insert data to 3 different tables in one view for example:

fooview:

add cards, add players, goals.

1. using insert query?
2. using 3 different table class?
3. or u have even better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go on with the table class because you can do the store and update functionality with the joomla inbuilt functions. [Read more](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JTable_class)

```
function store()
    {  
       //Get post data 
       $this->_data = $this->getPostData();

       $row = &$this->getTable('model_name');


       if (!$row->bind($this->_data))
       {
          $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());          
          return false;
       } 


       if (!$row->check())
       {         
         $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
         return false;
       } 


       if (!$row->store())
       {
         $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
         return false;
       }      
       $new_id = $this->_db->insertId();

       if($new_id > 0)
            $this->_data->id = $new_id;

       return true;
    }
```

set the post data as below

```
function getPostData()
    {
        $this->_data->id        = JRequest::getVar('id', 0, 'POST');
        $this->_data->field1    = JRequest::getVar('field1', '', 'POST' );
        $this->_data->field2    = JRequest::getVar('field2', '', 'POST' );
        return $this->_data; 
    }
```

if you have any questions please ask.

Comment: @Dasum Can you explain again where are your 3 tables?

Comment: They are joomla tables which exist in the your components. Please refer the read more link

Comment: Yes, but your code only saves data into one table while the question is about inserting into three different tables.

Comment: Yeah. That's why you have to use 3 joomla tables